# Does windows 10 support virtualbox?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I couldn't get it work on the anniversary version. I had tried to disable hyper-V, but it did nothing. Had no problem running virtualbox any version on Windows 7.

Anyone know how to get it work, can you tell my your configuration and step by step instructions?

Comment: yes, it does work fine.  what errors are you having specifically.

Comment: Which version of VB are you trying?  Might want to try a version or two back.  It's possible the latest release broke something for Windows 10; it's also possible a Windows update broke VB, in which case the devs will hopefully release a patch soon.

Comment: Maybe anecdotal, but I am running Windows 10 with whatever latest update, and virtualbox runs perfectly fine. I am running the latest version of VBox 5.1.14 if that helps